# Flutter web: blank screen when 'webdev build'

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a webpage with flutter web.
I tested it with the command

```
webdev serve
```

I can see the whole website,

But when I want to 'export / save' the website with this command:

```
webdev build
```

The webpage is blank, (when I open the html file in the build folder)

```
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 245ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 806ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 217ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 148ms
[INFO] Reading manifest at build/.build.manifest completed, took 1ms
[INFO] Deleting previous outputs in `build` completed, took 45ms
[INFO] Creating merged output dir `build` completed, took 226ms
[INFO] Writing asset manifest completed, took 4ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 671ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

If I open the html file in the build folder (that gives a blank screen). These are my errors in the console of google chrome:

[image: errorflutterweb]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a same issue but when I upload live server(host) it worked correctly. I am not sure but it can be about CORS, browser not allowed some source coming from outside of website so in local files has local source that means they are coming from outside the website as browser views. I think you should upload live server or local server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Works perfectly now! Thank you! Extra question: on the flutter website  they say you should use 'flutter build web' , but what's the difference with 'webdev build'?

Comment: You are welcome. I have no idea about it but I'm using both of them for build If I learn difference I'll share

Comment: faces to the same thing today once deployed under the account w/o internet access. Change to the user w. internet access and it worked as intended. thanks for hint!

Answer (score 3):

My flutter web app was displaying a blank page / blank screen too...

Try running the following in the terminal:

- `flutter channel dev`
- `flutter upgrade`
- `flutter run -d chrome`

If it still shows you a blank page (because it's not reaching your local server for some reason) terminate the current server 'ctrl + c'.

Then run `flutter run -d web` and the terminal will provide you with a new local host url. Follow the link and refresh it once & you should see your app running.